# How to convert html special characters into their codes using php

Tags: html-entities, htmlspecialchars

Actually I want to convert all the special characters into their codes as I've shown below:

```
!   &#33;    
"   &#34; 
#   &#35;    
$   &#36;    
%   &#37;    
&   &#38; 
'   &#39;    
(   &#40;    
)   &#41;    
*   &#42;    
+   &#43;    
,   &#44;    
-   &#45;    
.   &#46;    
/   &#47;
```

Is there any way to convert them into respected codes in php.

Answer (score -1):

There are functions called `html_entity_decode` and `htmlentities` in PHP.

Comment: Mate, just go here and check yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php There are different ways to encode things, find the particular one you want.

Comment: There's also htmlspecialchars which may be closer to your goal.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $str="&#33";
 echo html_entity_decode($str); //output !
```